# What level is release/debug  applied at in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation, release

I'm in the final stages of a project at the moment.  As part of my efforts, I have been reorganising the main MVC solution to use references to pre-compiled libraries, rather than having 15 different projects in the one solution.

My question relates to where the Release/Debug switch is applied.

Say for example, that my lower level libraries are built in Debug mode and my main web client app is built in Release mode.

Will the project be built in Release mode ( because that's the config of the main app ) or debug mode ( because the main app depends binaries compiled in debug mode )?

Comment: "Will the project be built" Which project do you mean, the main app or the library?  Visual Studio's debug/release setting is per-project, not per-solution.

Comment: Is it really necessary to pull out the various projects and reference the compiled libraries? Will you be developing against these other libraries independently, or will they only change with the main application? Are they only used with the main application? I ask out of curiosity.

Comment: @Adam - main project.  Essentially, I'm asking "if main app is built in release mode, does everything else honour that"?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton - Some stuff is already mature, unlikely to change and is used to support other projects.  Those are definite candidates for referenced DLLs.  It could be argued that I should have kept the app-specific stuff in the solution, but like I said in the OP, I had 15 projects in one solution.  Gets very very time-consuming in Solution Explorer.  No joke :)

Comment: If the number of projects/files to navigate through is the reason for this, check out the productivity power tools, Resharper or CodeMaid. All 3 have ways to speed up navigating large solutions. Also, you'll find that much larger solutions than 15 projects are the norm, there are 3 that I work on ATM that have 50+.

Comment: 50 projects in one solution.  Wow.  Don't get me wrong - I've easily referenced that many DLLs, but I've never seen the justification in having them all open at the same time.  Will look at the tools you mention.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @mlorbetske - Thank you so much for the Codemaid suggestion.  You've made a Saturday morning's coding a lot better.  If I could +1 you any more, I would :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scenario you describe, your web project will be built as a "Release" assembly and will depend on a "Debug" assembly. The reason for the quotes is that the only difference between a "Release" and "Debug" assembly (unless using non-default options) is the exclusion or inclusion, respectively, of debug symbols and optimization of the IL in the assembly. So, it is a perfectly valid situation to be in, having a release assembly referencing a debug assembly, though it's probably not one you want to be in. As there'll be more IL in the debug assembly (because its built wirhout optimizations) giving the JIT more work to do to try to optimize the code it will run on the machine, probably resulting in a not as optimized, slower experience at run time.

Depending on whether or not you are digitally signing your referenced assemblies, you could use a post-build task to replace the debug compiled, referenced assemblies with release compiled assemblies for your project's output.

An argument can be made that you should not be referencing debug compiled assemblies outside of the solution being used to create them, as the operative assumption for referencing a DLL as a file (as opposed to doing a project reference in the IDE) is that the assembly is a tested, finished version of the functionality it contains.

In summary, the way your project is compiled is not dependent on the build configurations of the assemblies it references, but, if possible, you should reference the release compiled versions of those assemblies instead.

Comment: So long story short, compilation is "release mode", but the JIT will need to do extra work to sort out the debug dependencies?

Comment: The JIT will take more time on the debug assemblies themselves, calls in to the debug libraries will take longer, code running in the release assembly should/will be faster than the code running in the debug assembly (assuming an apples to apples comparison on the executing code)